# Gulp + EJS + Expressjs how to send locals variable to ejs using gulp

Tags: express, parameters, gulp, render, ejs

[gulpfile]

```
import ejs from 'gulp-ejs';
/** other settings... **/
gulp.task('html', () => {
    return gulp.src(SRC.HTML)            
        .pipe(ejs({}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST.HTML));
});
```

[routes/users]

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    Members.findOne(req, function(user){
        res.render('users/login', {        
            test: user.name
        });
    });
}
```

[views/users/login.ejs]

```
<p><%= test %></p>
```

[Cmd]

```
> gulp
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: ReferenceError: G:\nodejs\gulp_test\src\views\users\login.ejs:1
 >> 1| <p><%= test %></p>

test is not defined
```

I want to pass local variables to the EJS file on the router.

However, the local variables that are passed to each router are dynamically different.

How do I configure it in gulpfile?
I need help seriously ... thank you.